# Email client that works with MDaemon

Tags: email, thunderbird, evolution, geary

Are there any Linux desktop email clients that work with the MDaemon email server's implementation of Activesync (EAS)? I'm desperately trying to wean myself off of Windows desktops but this is yet another obstacle.

I need to sync emails, calendars, tasks and notes.

I tried Evolution but it will not connect when selecting the EWS server type. IMAP and POP server types work but neither is adequate.

Answer (score 0):

One alternative may be to use [DavMail](http://davmail.sourceforge.net/), but be warned it's IMAP implementation is extremely limited, in that it lacks support for a number of important IMAP extensions, including UIDPLUS and the [lemonade profile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lemonade_Profile) set.

As for sites using Exchange, you best bet will likely be to ask your administrators to enable IMAP support in MDaemon directly.